# Kinesis PUT Limit, what does it mean exactly?

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Amazon claims that  kinesis streams can scale `"without limits"` but `"you should keep in mind"` that "Each shard can support up to 1000 PUT records per second" does this means that I cannot wright more then 1000 messages per second per stream?
Will I lose messages if I get over that number?

Answer (score 3):

> does this means that I cannot wright more then 1000 messages per second per stream?

No. The limits are *per shard*, not *per stream*. If you need more throughput, add more shards to your kinesis stream. You can keep adding shards as needed.

Comment: To answer the part about losing messages, it depends. If you're using the Kinesis Producer Library, then the KPL will receive the WriteThroughputExceededException, back off and retry. You will not lose messages unless you're really exceeding the PUT limit and run out of memory. If you're not using the KPL, then you will have to implement backoff and retry yourself, or you will lose messages.